# Observable<IEnumerable> get differences between sequence elements

Tags: c#, system.reactive

I have an observable that emits a sequence of IEnumerables

1: `[1,2,3,4]`

2: `[1,3,4]`

3: `[1,5,6]`

etc..

I want to try and create two observables from this:

- One that emits an IEnumerable of newly added elements:

1: `[1,2,3,4]`

2: `[]`

3: `[5, 6]`

etc..

- One that emits an IEnumerable of newly removed elements:

1: `[]`

2: `[2]`

3: `[3,4]`

etc..

Is there a way to do this using System.Reactive without having to rely on keeping a separate data structure to compare changes against?

Comment: No. Why doesn't all removed elements line 3 have 2 in it? What would a line 4 that doesn't include 5 generate?

Comment: I assume he meant 'newly removed elements' instead of 'all removed elements'.

Comment: And your answer assumes newly added elements, but I didn't think `Except` would work if source line 2 was `[3,4]` and added output line 3 was supposed to be `[5,6]` still.

Comment: @NetMage Shlomo is correct in that I meant newly removed elements. I'm not sure why I brain farted there, my bad! Ultimately I was looking for how to compare an element in the sequence with the one before it. Thanks both for your answers!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's fairly simple if you use `Observable.Zip` and `Enumerable.Except` to easily compare element n to element n-1.

```
public static class IObservableIEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> GetAddedElements<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        return source.Zip(source.StartWith(Enumerable.Empty<T>()), (newer, older) => newer.Except(older));
    }

    public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> GetRemovedElements<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> source)
    {
        return source.Zip(source.StartWith(Enumerable.Empty<T>()), (newer, older) => older.Except(newer));
    }
}
```

And here's some runner code:

```
var source = new Subject<IEnumerable<int>>();

var addedElements = source.GetAddedElements();
var removedElements = source.GetRemovedElements();

addedElements.Dump();   //Using Linqpad
removedElements.Dump(); //Using Linqpad

source.OnNext(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 });
source.OnNext(new int[] { 1, 3, 4 });
source.OnNext(new int[] { 1, 5, 6 });
```

Comment: Creating a new observable with an extra empty element at the front and then using that as the n-1 is genius! I kept trying to look into calling the source observable's `Last` and/or `Latest` element, but neither of those helped. Thanks again!

Comment: I'd suggest changing the queries to look like `source.Publish(s => s.Zip(s.StartWith(Enumerable.Empty<T>()), (newer, older) => newer.Except(older)));` to avoid any possible issues with multiple subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

If you expect adds and removes to be cumulative from the start of the sequence, you need something to remember what has come before.

```
public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> CumulativeAdded<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> src) {
    var memadd = new HashSet<T>();

    return src.Select(x => x.Where(n => memadd.Add(n)));
}

public static IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> CumulativeRemoved<T>(this IObservable<IEnumerable<T>> src) {
    var memdiff = new HashSet<T>();

    return src.Select(x => { foreach (var n in x) memdiff.Add(n); return memdiff.AsEnumerable().Except(x); });
}
```

}